# C++ socket communication with an external device

Tags: c++, tcp, tcpclient, ethernet, winsock2

So I've an industrial controller here and I wish to communicate with this device using my pc (windows 10), over ethernet tcp/ip.
This external device (controller) is connected directly to my pc via an ethernet cable and both my pc and the external device have a static IP address within the same range.

The manufacturer of this device has its own software with which I can communicate with the device over ethernet tcp/ip, however that is for configuring and programming the device.
I would like to make a small client application that uses sockets to send some command to this controller and should read the response from the device. The device is functioning as a server.
Important to know is that the commands should be sent in hexadecimal form to the device and it responds back with a message in hexadecimal form.

I am coding this in c++ in a visual studio 2022 environment.
So far I can connect to the external device (server), but  sending the command and reading the response does not seem it be working.
Another issue is that the error messages are not displayed in the console, even when I add a delay of 2 seconds everywhere.

Below is my code:

```
#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);


    if (WSAStartup(DllVersion, &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        cout << " Winsocket connection failed!" << endl;

        Sleep(2000);
        exit(1);
    }

    
    SOCKADDR_IN address;
    int addressLen = sizeof(address);
    IN_ADDR ipvalue;


    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.10");
    address.sin_port = htons(9100);
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;

    SOCKET connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);


    if (connect(connection, (SOCKADDR*)&address, addressLen) == 0) 
    {
        cout << "Connected" << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Error connecting to server" << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        exit(1);
    }
    


    char buffer[4096];
    string getInput;

    do
    {
        
        cout << ">input:";
        getline(cin, getInput);

        if (getInput.size() > 0) 
        { 
            // send  message
            int sendResult = send(connection, getInput.c_str(), getInput.size() + 1, 0);

            if (sendResult != SOCKET_ERROR) 
            {
                // Wait for response from server

                ZeroMemory(buffer, 4096);
                int bytesReceived = recv(connection, buffer, 4096, 0);

                if (bytesReceived) 
                {
                    // Response to client
                    cout << "SERVER> " << string(buffer, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;
                    Sleep(2000);
                }

                else
                    cout << "error " << endl;
                    Sleep(2000);

            }
        }
    }

    while (getInput.size() > 0);


}
```

Comment: Did you check all the errors that your api replied like `send` and `connect`? What are those error numbers.

Comment: I do not get error when I start the debugger in VS, only get two warnings: 
C4267: 'argument':conversion from 'size_t' to int, possible loss of data.
C4101: 'ipvalue' unreferenced local variable.

Comment: I meant the error of apis. What does `connect(..)` returns? You never catch the return code. What does `send(...)` returns? Code doesn't have `else` to check for error codes.

Comment: Also a bare `else` without curly brackets only accepts single line. So the 3 lines of`else cout...; Sleep(...);` and `Sleep` would be executed all the time.

Comment: The send() function returns the amount of bytes sent if successful otherwise it returns an errorcode. Similar for connect(). I already know that the connect is successful because, I see on the console "connected", so that's good. 
I will rewrite the code so I try to catch the return of these functions.

Comment: You might need [`WSAGetLastError()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/return-values-on-function-failure-2) to get real error.